How to not get redirected to localhost when trying to access an Apache 2 ran server on Ubuntu in the same network?
I am currently hosting an Apache 2 server on an Ubuntu 24.04 server that is hosted on a VirtualBox ISO however when I tried to put the network into bridged mode as someone recommended it now works half way because if I go to the IP address it automatically redirects to localhost instead of the 192.168.1.208 IP that is the IP that I gave it.
I mean that it automatically replaces the IP that I input in the address bar to localhost and then gives an error that it is not an availbable site as if you were to type in an invalid url of http://asdffdsajklasdfjl.com/.
I can access the localhost from the box itself but I cannot from any other host than the box itself. I am using Chrome on my phone or laptop to try to access the site from the same WiFi that the VirtualBox is on. The network is bridged to my Windows 11 Pro laptop  Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160Mz Adapter  with adapter type Intel PRO/1000MT Desktop. I am using my phone to try to visit the website from the same Wifi . IP of bridged host:
192.168.1.208 netmask 255.255.255.0 with broadcast 192.168.1.255

Is there any configuration file that I have to change as I don't want to randomly change config files and ruin my hosting and server.
cURL request to 192.168.1.208 from computer inside network:
C:\Users\miche>curl -ILk 192.168.1.208
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2024 14:50:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu)
location: index.php?module=Users&view=Login
Set-Cookie: YTSID=5f6s0bn2sbqt7d25jisi9n905d; path=/; domain=192.168.1.208; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2024 14:50:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu)
location: https://localhost/
Set-Cookie: YTSID=gegtsji928s64dfu1n6eu5mo9e; path=/; domain=192.168.1.208; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Expires: Mon, 26 Aug 2024 14:50:15 GMT
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Aug 2024 14:50:15 GMT
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Expect-Ct: enforce; max-age=3600
X-Frame-Options: same origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Robots-Tag: none
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https://api.yetiforce.eu *.tile.openstreetmap.org; font-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'nonce-ca8058e15ddcb4f2045cdeea30f33c275256f8a60b37756e8e76c010e4153f84'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; frame-src 'self' mailto: tel:; style-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; object-src 'none';
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443 after 2227 ms: Couldn't connect to server

cURL from Windows machine that is hosting the VM is not the VM itself:
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2024 14:44:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu)
location: index.php?module=Users&view=Login
Set-Cookie: YTSID=1ldec8fmkin3c3p74h02kv8i0a; path=/; domain=192.168.1.208; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2024 14:44:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu)
location: https://localhost/
Set-Cookie: YTSID=nup3gm0fl5me2ulem6t4odntm8; path=/; domain=192.168.1.208; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Expires: Mon, 26 Aug 2024 14:44:29 GMT
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Aug 2024 14:44:29 GMT
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Expect-Ct: enforce; max-age=3600
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Robots-Tag: none
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https://api.yetiforce.eu *.tile.openstreetmap.org; font-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'nonce-7f01a261d9770adc9e0f34963e5de44c868890594e279af6ba14d0fd0bca1eff'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; frame-src 'self' mailto: tel:; style-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; object-src 'none';
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2024 14:44:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3
Location: https://localhost/dashboard/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2024 14:44:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3
Last-Modified: Sun, 19 Nov 2023 11:10:25 GMT
ETag: "1443-60a7f6a8cca40"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 5187
Content-Type: text/html

It is requesting the right headers of index.php?module=Users&view=Login but seems to have some other problem.
000-default conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost> 

For my own website config called "new" (new.conf):
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.1.208
    ServerAlias 192.168.1.208
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/new
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/new">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName 192.168.1.208
    ServerAlias 192.168.1.208
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/new

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/lukas/certificates/server.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/lukas/certificates/private.key

    <Directory "/var/www/new">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


You will need to share a bit more information. First about your Apache server. What is the IP address and what is the mask. To which adapter on the host is the virtual host bridged? What are the IP and mask of the host? What do you mean with "it works halfway" Can you access the Apache server from the virtualbox host? Add the information to the question, please.

I meant that it works in the way that it does see the server but does not access the correct site and redirects to localhost. Regarding the  apache config file give me a second to upload the  config file

Please [edit] your question and add the requested information. What browser or other HTTP client do you use and on which system do you run it? What exactly do you mean with "if I go to the IP Address it automatically redirects to localhost"? What URL do you use? Do you mean a HTTP redirect or the name resolution? Maybe show the relevant network traffix.

"I can access the localhost from the box itself but I cannot from any other host than the box itself" - that's to be expected. The name "localhost" literally means the local host - i.e. itself

So it isnt possible to visit an apache server that is hosted on a computer on a network from within the network itself. I am solely using localhost to refer to myself if I visit the site on the laptop itself but I use my local IP on my other device to try to access the site I am hosting on my laptop VM.

"So it isnt possible to visit an apache server that is hosted on a computer on a network from within the network itself." - of course it is. We're trying to understand your network configuration to spot the issues

edited it into the post @Bodo

Your configuration is tying the website names to IP addresses probably inappropriately. For example, consider this snippet:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.1.208
    ServerAlias 192.168.1.208
    …
</VirtualHost>

First off, unless you are in a specialist situation the ServerName value should be a server name, not address. Next, the optional ServerAlias can contain alternate names for the same virtual host. There's no point having it repeat the same entry.
Right now this configuration will match only on the "name" 192.168.1.208. It won't match on localhost, and it won't match on any other name. (Actually it might, but only if you've a badly misconfigured Apache without a default ServerName entry.)
Don't use localhost as a name, because for every host in the world this is a reserved name that means "me, myself". On my primary machine here http://localhost will return me a web page from my test webserver. On a secondary machine here http://localhost will fail because it (the local host, i.e. itself) isn't running a web server.
If you intend referencing this website only as 192.168.1.208 then put that in the ServerName. Otherwise you need to set up DNS (or /etc/hosts on every machine in your network) and assign a name to the address. Here's an example for a website accessible as http://myfirstwebsite that you can also access as http://192.168.1.200:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myfirstwebsite
    ServerAlias 192.168.1.208
    …
</VirtualHost>

Finally, as a general case, the IP address for your VM must be unique on your network. As must every other IP address for a device on your network. Don't try to use the same IP address for your Host and your VM Guest.

Looking at the headers you’ve posted, what is index.php?module=Users&view=Login? It seems to me this is not an Apache issue but rather whatever that PHP application is is forcing the web page to redirect to localhost.
My bet is you installed some kind of PHP-based software (YetiForceCRM?) on that machine and it defaulted to use localhost as a domain name on install. Now, it tries to constantly use localhost to connect but that is obviously wrong. Perhaps that localhost config setting should be 192.168.1.208 instead?
Note: I guessed you installed YetiForceCRM based on a Google search for the parameter fragment index.php?module=Users&view=Login?. If it is somehow not YetiForceCRM, please let us know what software you have happened to install.
